# NullPointerException in OnEditorActionListener

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I get NullPointerException while pressing Enter in my Android project. I google it, and people got same problem becase they didn't set findViewByIt. Unfortunately I got it. What's going on - why I got exception?

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
        textPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PrintToast(textPassword.getText().toString());
               }
             });
        textPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                try
                {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN))
                    {
                    buttonLogin.performClick();
                    }
                }
                catch ( Exception e) {
                      PrintToast(e.toString());
                }
                return false;
            }

        });



    }
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainPage" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/PIN_label_HelloMsg"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="@string/PIN_button_AcceptPIN" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/PIN_label_EnterPIN"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberPassword" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: there is no error in logcat. I clear it, run project and pressed Enter. Maybe because I run my Android project via usb device (Nexus 7)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
            textPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
             buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            textPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    try
                    {
                    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN))
                        {
                        buttonLogin.performClick();
                        }
                    }
                    catch ( Exception e) {
                          PrintToast(e.toString());
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            });
```

**[EDIT]** This works fine

```
Button buttonLogin;
EditText textPassword ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
textPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, textPassword.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
         });
    textPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {

            @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
            KeyEvent event) {

         if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
             // do your stuff here

            buttonLogin.performClick();
            Log.e("Called","Called OKKKKKK");
            return true;
            }

        Log.e("Called","Called");

        return false;

    }

    });



}
```

Comment: Copy & paste. Unfortunately, still error. Application crash after pressing enter.

Answer (score 2):

the button is not bound to your layout:

```
buttonLogin.performClick();
```

here you get the NPE.
Add this after `setContentView`:

```
        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
```

Comment: Yes, it's not bound. (I bound it in my code under textPassword) But still I have exception.

Comment: buttonLogin is null! you cannot execute any method on it. textPassword is textPassword not buttonLogin...

Comment: I changed my code in question. Still the same problem. I also clear my project and device.

Comment: consider it done, I don't know how to get error trace (but I am working on it)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I wanted to clarify the reason behind this issue in hopes people can understand the why and not just the fix.

**Actionable Key Events**

[OnEditActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html) is listening for specific actionable events, not for KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN events. Historically its been used for the actionable buttons on the SoftIME (virutal keyboard), i.e. the search, next, or newline button, and its implementation is geared towards that usage.

**Hardware Key Events**

[OnKeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) can be used for specific key entry, or special key events like KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, or KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BOOKMARK. However, it is used for Hardware keyboard events only.

**Real-time Text Changes Hard/Soft Keyboards**

For event changes to the entire TextView/EditText you can use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) which will be triggered each time the Editable area is modified. With some slight modification you can hook into and check for specific character changes.

**The Why**

OnEditActionListener is listening for *actionable* events, and is doing so by hooking into the view hierarchies system callbacks. This means that depending on the latency of the framework, and how events are propagated to children callbacks, that some events may have already been consumed at the time they reach us.

Regardless of the event being null or not, we still have the ability to check for the action through the actionId (which is, I'm assuming why it is given).

TCA's answer is correct, but I'll add my implementation just for thoroughness and to add some extras.

```
    textPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            switch( actionId ) {
                case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
                    // clear textPassword focus and hide SoftIME
                    textPassword.clearFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textPassword.getWindowToken(), 0);

                    // call buttonLogin OnClickListener through performClick, if it exists
                    buttonLogin.performClick();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```